# Sessions with express.js + passport.js

Tags: express, socket.io, passport.js

**Goal**

What I want to do:

- Create a session for the user
- Create a session for the socket (`socket.io`)
- Use `passport.js` to authenticate the login and `socket` sessions.

**Notes**

I have installed `MongoStore` and `passport.socket.io npm's`. I can login and set the `cookie` of the user logged in (`connect.sid`)

---

**QUESTION**

How do I setup the system to store `socket` sessions and couple them with the `session` of the user?

---

**Code**

app.js

```
  /* The usual express setup */
  passport = require('passport'),
  LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
  User = require('./models/user.js'),
  MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);

app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: 'chuck norris', 
    store: new MongoStore({db: User.name}, // the db's name
        function(err) {
          console.log(err || 'connect ok!');
        })
  }));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(app.router);
```

---

app.js (the passport part)

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, user) {
      if(!user) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Username!'});
      }
      if(!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect Password!'});
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

app.post('/',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
    function(req, res) {
      res.redirect('/home/'+req.user.username);
    });
```

---

app.js (socket.io part)

```
io.set('authorization', passportSocket.authorize({
  key: 'connect.sid',
  secret: 'chuck norris',
  store: /* Not entirely sure what goes here */
  fail : function(data, accept) { accept(null, false); },
  success: function(data, accept) { accept(null, true); }
}));


io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('User Connected: ' + socket.handshake.user.username);
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You store your new memory story object instance into a variable and pass it in to both express and socket io like so.
(be aware that we are using different stores but in theory it should not matter what store you use as long as you pass off control the proper way)...

```
var ...
,MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore
,sessionStore = new MemoryStore();
```

then in app.configure you...

```
app.use(express.session({store:sessionStore,secret:'secret',key:'express.sid'}));
```

and finally in socket.io configure

```
io.configure(function (){
io.set("authorization", passportSocketIo.authorize({
    key:    'express.sid',       //the cookie where express (or connect) stores its session id.
    secret: 'secret', //the session secret to parse the cookie
    store:   sessionStore,     //the session store that express uses
    fail: function(data, accept) {
        // console.log("failed");
        // console.log(data);// *optional* callbacks on success or fail
        accept(null, false);             // second param takes boolean on whether or not to allow handshake
    },
    success: function(data, accept) {
      //  console.log("success socket.io auth");
     //   console.log(data);
        accept(null, true);
    }
}));
```

If you have done this correctly and your user successfully authenticates you should then be able to access the session data on the handshake object.

```
console.log(socket.handshake.user.username);
//or sometimes it might be...
console.log(socket.handshake.user[0].username);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. One more thing, when the server is restarted, the users session gets deleted and the page goes back to the login screen.

Comment: When you say one more thing are you saying you need me to answer why your session gets deleted and goes back to login???

Comment: I think that is the proper behavior.  Once you restart the server it should start all new sessions.   This is because you have to reauthenticate after restart and a new session id is generated after authentication.   Are you saying you want to sessions to persist after server restart also?

Comment: I saw when I was playing around with the MongoStore, the session persisted. But It makes sense to reinstantiate the session once the server is restarted. Thanks for your help, very much appreciated!

Comment: Is 'express.sid' as the session key the convention or is it a requirement? I've tried other strings and they've worked just fine, so I was wondering why it's used in so many examples.

Comment: Its just a convention like you probably have figured out by now you can use whatever you want there.

Comment: "and finally in session.io configure" << did you mean socket.io ?