# User authification with node js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I know there are a lot of treads about this, but i really didn't found what i am looking for.

So I want to make user login with node js, i am using express, mongo  db but most of all socket.io. So I want people to fill a custom form, from my index.html :

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/../index.html', 'utf8', function(err, text){
    res.send(text);
  });
});

<form method="get" id="lala" >
   <input type="text" name="user">
   <input type="text" name="user">
   <button id="button">KOKo</button>
</form>
```

on button click :

```
socket.emit('checkLogin', { my collected data from the form });
```

so now on the server side I would like to check this username and password and if they are ok, ( i dont know how is it here, but in php I make `SESSION['user_id']` ( for example) so after that when user comes back for another request I can check this session and I know that the user is logged in and he cna see the page.
I did saw passport.js mongo-db session store, but i wasn't been able to make any of the demoes working. I couldn't found out how to store the session, how to check the session, and all this kind of stuff.

So if someone could help me and write down a demo for idiot like me like:

```
function check_auth_user(username,password,done,public_id){
  var sql="SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE username = '"+ username +"' and password = '"+ password +"' limit 1";
  connection.query(sql, function (err,results) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if(results.length > 0){

      var res=results[0]; 
      passport.serializeUser(function(res, done) {
        done(null,res);
      });

      passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
        done(null,res);
      });
      return done(null, res);
    } else {
      return done(null, false); 
    }
  });
}
```

but now how can I set the session into the store and how i am supposed to reach it after that ? and also how to send it to the correct user connected from the socket io :-)

Comment: Explanation of how to use sessions in express - http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-sessions

Comment: Thanks for editing my post :-). Ok this is finally a very very good demo that I can undestand more about the sessions. Now May I ask how can I reach this "req" param in my socket functions. Because the only param I get is just socket which i dont know how to return so I can console.log him. WHen I try I get:
 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)

Answer (score 3):

Passport handles most of it for you.

First, you misunderstood `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` methods. You should call them once during the initialization of your app to register  global helpers. Passport will use them to serialize user object into user_id after authentication and to serialize it back to user object every time user hits your API.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(res, done) {
  done(null, res.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  var sql="SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = '"+ id +"' limit 1";
  connection.query(sql, function (err, results) {
    done(err, results[0])
  });
});
```

So, it makes `check_auth_user` function really simple:

```
function check_auth_user(username, password, done){
  var sql="SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE username = '"+ username +"' and password = '"+ password +"' limit 1";
  connection.query(sql, function (err, results) {
    done(err, results[0])
  });
}

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(check_auth_user));
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  successRedirect: '/'
}));
```

Passport will store `user_id` in express session automatically, populating `req.user` with full deserialized user, but you should ensure that both `express.session` and `passport.session` middlewares are enabled.

```
app.use(express.session({
  secret: "very secret",
  store: new RedisStore() // or any other Store
}));
app.use(passport.session());
```

Now, you'll be able to access your user object with `req.user`:

```
app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {
  if (req.user) {
    res.send('Hello, ' + req.user.username + ', your id is ' + req.user.id);
  } else {
    res.send('Hello anonymous');
  }
});
```

Comment: I know this question will be really redicilous but - i really dont undestand what is the connection now between 'check_auth_user' and 'passport'. Is It this function done ? And if it is can you gimme a link to a documentation about it :-). And still how to get this param "req" inside socket.io functions if you know.

Comment: Looks like I missed the part that you're using `socket.io` and not http calls. Probably, you'll need some additional module to handle authentication throuh `socket.io`. You should look at [passport.socketio module](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093018/sessions-with-express-js-passport-js).

Comment: ah, ok but I have to go now, I will test it tonight, but I thing i tested it it seems complicated even the demo looks simple :-). I think the problem was I need different vesion of the socket.io to make this work, not just the module. Or may be I got it wrong.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that `passport` is a good choice for `socket.io`. My answer was based on wrong assumption that you're using HTTP and express.